# Bundle (Symfony 4): incapable to load Configuration from YAML, namespace issue

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony and PHP and I'm trying to create a **Bundle** to implement a login authentication web API.

You can find the the code of the Bundle inside [this stripped down Symfony Application on GitHub](https://github.com/danidom/stackQuestion). The Bundle code is inside [src](https://github.com/danidom/stackQuestion/tree/master/src/upm/LdapAuthBundle).

I've read many if not all of the questions I've found on the topic but I'm incapable of solving my issue:

When starting the server from the console the error I receive is:
**There is no extension able to load the configuration for "ldap_auth" (in config/packages\ldap_auth.yaml). Looked for namespace "ldap_auth", found none**

After trying many solutions I cannot understad what the problem is and I'm very thankful for any help.

Comment: post the relevant code within the question

Comment: Seems to me like you're putting to `/src` what has to go to `/vendor`. I concluded so by `composer.json` file, which is in your `src/upm/LdapAuthBundle` folder. You should read on how to maintain packages with composer...

Answer (score 2):

You are miss understanding the configuration process.  Which is understandable.  It's complex.  Config files are loaded for you and then your extension/configuration is called.  You don't load them explicitly.

You may seen some files being loaded by extensions but those are for defining services not configuration.

The solution is to remove the loader stuff from your extension:

```
// LdapAuthExtension
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    // *** Remove these lines
    //$loader = new YamlFileLoader( $container,
      //  new FileLocator('config/packages')
    //);
    //$loader->load('ldap_auth.yaml');

    if ($config['app_id']) {
        $container->setParameter('ldap_auth.app_id', $config['app_id']);
    }
}
```

By the way, linking to a github repository with a complete non-working example made this very easy to trouble shoot.  Wish more people would do this.